# Fixing deprecation [DEP0062] for Node.js in Visual Studio 2015 with launch.json

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create a basic 'Hello World' web server with Node.js v8.9.1 using Visual Studio 2015 and I'm getting stopped by this warning:

```
(node:16764) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.
```

The meaning of this warning is [simple](https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0062_node_debug): the old `node --debug` needs to be replaced with the new `node --inspect`. *How* to make that change is where I am getting stuck. `node --debug` is getting used automatically and is not in any file that I can see, and the way to replace or overwrite that automatic value is not clear.

[This thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32529) tells me that I need to alter my `launch.json` file to overwrite the protocol for `node --debug`, which sounds plausible, but `launch.json` is not a file that I can see. I found the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) to altering my launch configurations, but those instructions do not line up with what I'm seeing... I do not see the "Configuration gear icon on the Debug view top bar" like it says I should, and I'm not sure if it matters what folder I set up the launch configuration file in.

At the very bottom of that [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_common-questions) is an FAQ with that problem, confirming that I need to set up `launch.json` and not saying *how* to set up the file, although I have a gist of [what it should like](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-node-debug2/blob/master/testapp/.vscode/launch.json).

Assuming that `launch.json` is the solution to my depreciation error, how should I set up that file in Visual Studio 2015?

EDIT: For reference I'm adding a screenshot. Also, I was following [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2015-Final-Release-Event/Nodejs-Tools-for-Visual-Studio) guide and hit this snag about 3 minutes in.

[image: looking for launch.json]

UPDATE: I found `node.exe --debug` in the file `Web.Debug.config` and changed it to `node.exe --inspect`, but the same error still occurs.